# How to correct this rewrite rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url as
 `http://www.mydomain.com/levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c`. I need to change this url to `http://www.mydomain.com/medium`. 
I am not familiar with rewrite url.

I tried with `RewriteRule ^medium/?$    levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c`, but not worked correctly.

Full rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^medium/?$    levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rewrite rule worked fine

```
RewriteRule ^medium.*$  /levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change only that line to:

```
RewriteRule ^medium /levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c
```

Or if you don't care if anything is after medium is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^medium(.*) /levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c
```

Comment: And with a `[L,QSA]` at the and of the line?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are in the wrong order, try changing them to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^medium/?$    levels/home?mode=48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed5c

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The conditions need to be applied to the index.php rule, and not the medium rule. `RewriteCond`s are only applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`, not all of them.